# General topology Action

Tags: general-topology

Would you know:

Find a nontrivial action $Z_n \rightarrow S^1 $ of the cyclic group of order $n$ on the circle and compute the quotient space?

Comment: What have you tried on your own?  Do you have work you can show us?  This sounds a lot like a homework problem, and although people here would be glad to help, we're not going to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Think of a natural manipulation of the circle that, when performed $n$ times, brings each point on the circle back to where it started.

Comment: And to obtain the quotient space after defining the action is not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Can I represent $n$ times obtaining and bringing each point on the circle back such as: $[n]*p = (-1)^n * p$? It would mean that all points lying on one line, but there are just two point lying on one line, because it is $S^1$,  would be identical and the quotient would be space $\mathbb{RP}^1$.

What do you think? :)